# como puedo extraer los colores de un json con foreach - while?

Tags: php

como puedo extraer los colores de este json?

```
[{
"item1": "si",
"item2": "no",
"item3":
[ 
{
"color": "azul",
"tipo": "circulo"
},
{
"color": "rojo",
"tipo": "triangulo" 
},
{
"color": "verde",
"tipo": "cuadrado"
}
]
}
]
```

esto es lo que hago y si extraigo el item1 e item2, pero en el item3 me muestra la pabra Array.

```
$array = json_decode($data);  

foreach($array as $colors=>$color){
echo "$colors:<br>";
while (list($clave,$valor)=each($color)){
echo "$clave=$valor<br>";
}
}
```

Comment: Tienes un array entre cuyas llaves puede haber una que contenga colores y tipos? O sabes de antemanoque el item3 siempre contiene valores y tipos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, esto que haces para decodear:

```
$array = json_decode($data);
```

Está parseando $data como un objeto. Por el nombre de la variable interpreto que quieres un array, así que

```
$array = json_decode($data,true);
```

Hecho esto, si sabes que tu item3 tiene la forma `item3 = >[{color,tipo},{color,tipo},{color,tipo}]` y quieres imprimir su contenido.

```
foreach($array['item3'] as $pares){

    echo "Colores:<br>";

    foreach($pares as $llave=>$valor) {
        echo "$llave = $valor <br>";
    }
}
```

Debiera entregarte:

```
Colores:
  color=azul,
  tipo=circulo
Colores:
  color= rojo,
  tipo=triangulo
Colores:
  color=verde,
  tipo=cuadrado
```

Puede que esto no sea exactamente lo que necesitas hacer. Si quieres un algoritmo para recorrer un array genérico verificando si alguna de sus llaves tiene un valor con forma de array, se hace más o menos igual con un poco más de lógica añadida.

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in..linea.**** foreach($array['item3'] as $pares){

Comment: Significa que $array no tiene la estructura que nos dijiste. Añade la salida de var_dump($array) a tu pregunta.

Answer (score 1):

prueba esto

```
foreach($data as $colors => $color){
    echo "$colors:<br>";
    while (list($clave,$valor)=each($color)){
        if (is_array($valor)) {
            $string = '';
            foreach ($valor as $v) {
                $string .= ' '.$v['color'];
            }
            $valor = $string;
        }
        echo "$clave = $valor<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Llevo todo el dia y no me sale, este es el error**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in.....

Comment: Que linea? no te dice'

Comment: e cambiado el $data por $array pero no salen los colores, esta es la linea****foreach($array as $colors => $color){

Comment: ese array con esos json como los cosultas?

Comment: con java, mi intencion es extraer de un json de ese tipo unos datos para pasarlos como parametros

Comment: y ya le hiciste un var_dump a $data o $array (no se como lo tengas), para ver que data te está mostrando?